# rvm fails to install ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm, failed-installation

Trying to install ruby using rvm. Keeps failing at config. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is the error I get..

```
ruby-2.3.1 - #configuring.......................

Error running './configure --prefix=/home/ronnie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /home/ronnie/.rvm/log/1468710018_ruby-2.3.1/configure.log

checking utime.h presence... yes

checking for utime.h... yes

checking gmp.h usability... yes

checking gmp.h presence... yes

checking for gmp.h... yes

checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... yes

checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no

checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64

checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no

checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes

checking whether char is unsigned... no

checking for inline... no

checking for working volatile... no

checking for typeof syntax and keyword spelling... __typeof__

configure: error: ANSI C-conforming const and volatile are mandatory

There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```